# Parse an array of strings

Tags: julia, text-parsing

I have a 1D array of strings ( Array{String,1} ) which describe a matrix of Floats (see below). I need to parse this matrix. Any slick suggestions?

- Julia 1.5
- MacOS

Yes, I did read this in from a file. I don't want to read the whole thing in using CSV, because I want to maintain the option to read the entire file using memory I/O, which I don't think CSV has. Plus, I have some complex lines including strings and numbers, and strings and strings that I need to parse, which kind of rules out DelimitedFiles. The columns are separated by two spaces.

```
julia> lines[24+member_total:idx-1]
49-element Array{String,1}:
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.3308000E+01"
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.9987500E-01  1.3308000E+01"
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.1998650E+00  1.3308000E+01"
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  2.1998550E+00  1.3308000E+01"
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  3.1998450E+00  1.3308000E+01"
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  4.1998350E+00  1.3308000E+01"
 ⋮
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  5.9699895E+01  1.4000000E-01"
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  6.0199890E+01  1.0100000E-01"
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  6.0699885E+01  6.2000000E-02"
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  6.1199880E+01  2.3000000E-02"
 "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  6.1500000E+01  0.0000000E+00"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am strongly against reinventing the wheel and using custom-made parsers due to practivcal robustness of such solutions in production.

If your file is in a single `String` use:

```
using DelimitedFiles
readdlm(IOBuffer(strs))
```

If your file as a `Vector` of `String`s use

```
cat(readdlm.(IOBuffer.(strsa))...,dims=1)
```

Finally, there is not conflict in using memory maps togehther with CSV:

```
using Mmap

s = open("d.txt") # d.txt contains your lines
                  # if you want to read & wrtie use "w+" option
 
m = Mmap.mmap(s, Vector{UInt8}) # memory mapping of your file

readdlm(IOBuffer(m))
```

At the same time you can always set the stream to the beginning and read the data regardless the memory map:

```
seek(s,0)
readdlm(s)
seek(s,0) # reset the stream
```

Comment: As am I. Thanks, this is a really slick solution. I didn't think of using IOBuffer to input to CSV or readdlm. For those of you like me, strs is the string that contains your file, and strsa is the array of strings holding your file. @PrzemyslawSzufel I have a couple of questions for you cause it is obvious you are a julia expert. Do you have a slick way of parsing strings  that have numbers and letters (I just want the numbers)? For instance:
 ```"         49   kp_total        - Total number of key points (-) [must be at least 3]"```

Comment: Do you know a good way of taking these values that I read in (matrices, strings and scalars), and writing them to file with other strings (titles, variable names and explanations, as seen in my above question. I read in a string that has my scalar value I want, the var name and then an explanation. One I change the scalar value, I'm going to write that back to file.) ?

Comment: For the question 1 having to extract such data from `String`s I would try regular expressions or in more complex cases semantic analysis of the text. For the question 2 the most natural answer is to use the JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

```
strs = ["0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.3308000E+01",
        "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.9987500E-01  1.3308000E+01",
        "0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  1.1998650E+00  1.3308000E+01"]

mapreduce(vcat, strs) do s
    (parse.(Float64, split(s, "  ")))'
end
```

```
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0       13.308
 0.0  0.0  0.199875  13.308
 0.0  0.0  1.19986   13.308
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a work around. Not the most slick thing, but it works...

```
function rmspaces(line)
    line = replace(line, "\t" => " ")
    # println("line: ", line)
    while occursin("  ", line)
        line = replace(line, "  "=>" ")
        # println("line: ", line)
    end

    return line
end

function readmatrix(lines, numcolumns::Int64; type=Float64)
    #Remove the spaces to one
    for i=1:length(lines)
        lines[i] = rmspaces(lines[i])
    end

    matrix = zeros(length(lines), numcolumns)

    for i=1:length(lines)
        idx = 1 # set the initial stop at the beginning
        spot = 1
        for j=1:length(lines[i])
            if lines[i][j]==' ' && j>1 #Stops at spaces
                number = parse(type,lines[i][idx:j]) #from the last stop to this one
                idx = j #Set this stop in memory
                matrix[i,spot] = number
                spot += 1
            end
        end
        if spot<numcolumns+1 #If there isn't a space after the last number,
            #we need to attach the last number in every row. If the last number
            #was appended, then the spot will be increased to be more than the number
            #of columns.
            number = parse(type, lines[i][idx:end])
            matrix[i,spot] = number
        end
    end
    return matrix
end
```